# Applying different margins/slugs to different pages

Tags: adobe-indesign

My client wants the following margins/slugs:

[image]

However I don't see anywhere an option in inDesign to apply this automatically to all pages (my document is 12 pages long). How to do that?

A second question I have is: should the edges of the yellow zone in this image be slugs or margins?

Comment: Slug is for placing comments on diffrent sections. Do you mean bleed? Also, doesnt it work when you set the marges at the master page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by that image, the yellow "Live work area" looks like a safe zone for text and images. It looks like a double page spread and they are saying that you should avoid setting text and important images outside of that area otherwise you risk them being obscured on the inner margins (possibly by the curl of the pages as they disappear into the spine) or trimmed on the outer edges if the registration is off.

A quick not on slugs, bleeds and margins.

**Margins** are areas within the document, **bleed** is the allowance outside of the trim edge to allow for any registration issues (movement) when the final print job is cut, and **slugs** are the areas where any production notes are applied (usually outside the bleed area). So in answer to your question, the yellow area should be margins.

To set up these pages it should be simple from the first `New > Document...` dialogue box if you follow the example below. Note the check box for **facing pages** and the inside and outside margin measurements.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful, thx. However my document is already created and in inDesign 9.2 margins are set in Layout > Margins. In it, I can set "Inside" to "15 mm" and the rest to "5 mm", but when clicking OK inDesign applies 15 mm to all margins anyway! If I come back to the same dialog box, all values are set to "15 mm". Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: There is a chain logo in-between the margin measurements,have you de-checked it so it looks "broken" before entering the margin dimensions?

Comment: You're welcome! Hope all is ok!

Comment: Wait, it applied only to the two pages visible on the screen, but not to the rest of my pages!

Comment: If you create the guides when you first open the document, the margins and guides should remain for every subsequent page you create. However, as you said you've been supplied the document, you must amend the guides on the master pages.

If you double click on A-Master in the top of the Pages palette you will be taken to the master pages where you can input the new margins. This should then be applied to all A-Master pages that you create from then on.

Comment: Works, thans a lot!